# Invalidate Cache after Programmatically Creating Groups in Keycloak

Tags: keycloak

I've created a custom Keycloak provider that listens to a Kafka topic and creates groups that correspond to messages received on the topic.

I've got it mostly working.  The only hurdle I still need to overcome is that after I create a group, I don't see it listed in either the admin UI, or in an API call to get the list of groups for the realm.  But I do know that these groups are being saved in the database, because if I stop and restart Keycloak, then they're present.

I'm guessing this has to do with the Infinispan cache not being updated.  I need to somehow tell the cache to refresh itself.  Does anybody know how to do this?

The other thing that's a bit odd is that I had to create my own KeycloakSession for this flow, and a TransactionManager along with it in order to manage the transactions.  This is a fairly unique situation, in that the actions being triggered in Keycloak are not associated with a user's session; they're driven off of Kafka messages.  Not sure if this has something to do with it.

My setup is like this:

- I created a custom Spi implementation called `GroupSyncApi`.
- I defined interfaces `GroupSyncProvider` and `GroupSyncProviderFactory` that extend `Provider` and `ProviderFactory` respectively
- The `GroupSyncProvider` has one method: `void listen(KeycloakSessionFactory keycloakSessionFactory)`
- I created implementations `KafkaGroupSyncProvider` and `KafkaGroupSyncProviderFactory` to implement my custom interfaces.
- The `listen` implementation instantiates a class called `KafkaTopicListener`.  This starts a Kafka Consumer and associated code to process the messages in a new thread.  The `listen` method is called from the `postInit` method of the provider factory.  This starts the thread and the Kafka consumer.
- When a message is received (as JSON), I deserialize it and create a Keycloak group that corresponds to it.  I do this as follows (this is in my `KafkaTopicListener` class:

  ```
  public void listen(KeycloakSessionFactory keycloakSessionFactory) {
      while (true) {
          final ConsumerRecords<String, EntityEvent> records = consumer.poll(Duration.of(5, ChronoUnit.SECONDS));
          if (!records.isEmpty()) {
              KeycloakSession keycloakSession = keycloakSessionFactory.create();
              keycloakSession.getTransactionManager().begin();
              GroupModel entitiesParent = keycloakSession.realms().getTopLevelGroups(realm).stream().filter(groupModel -> "entities".equals(groupModel.getName())).findFirst().get();

              records.forEach(record -> {
                  logger.info("Received event on Kafka '" + record.topic() + "' topic.  " + record.value().getType() + " corresponding entity group with id: " + record.value().getEntity().getId() + "; name: " + record.value().getEntity().getName());
                  switch (record.value().getType()) {
                      case CREATE:
                          doCreate(keycloakSession, realm, record.value(), parent);
                          break;
                  }
              }
              keycloakSession.getTransactionManager().commit();
              consumer.commitAsync();
          }
      }
  }

  private void doCreate(KeycloakSession keycloakSession, RealmModel realm, EntityEvent event, GroupModel entitiesParent) {
      GroupModel group = keycloakSession.realms().createGroup(realm, event.getEntity().getName());
      group.setAttribute("type", singleValue("entity"));
      group.setParent(entitiesParent);
  }
  ```

The parts I'm unclear on are:

- Am I correctly creating a group?
- Is my KeycloakSession set up correctly?  I had to manually create it since this code flow is not part of an HTTP request.
- Is my transaction manager set up correctly?

Comment: Can you provide more information about your setup? Why did you create a custom provider? Aren't you using the Admin REST API?

Comment: Added some more information about what I'm trying to do.  This code flow is outside any REST API; it is driven by Kafka messages.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution.  The issue was with how I assigned my group to its parent group.  I did this:

```
group.setParent(entitiesParent);
```

But digging through Keycloak source code (I looked at the admin API endpoints in `GroupsResource` where groups are created), I see that Keycloak instead does:

```
realm.moveGroup(group, entitiesParent);
```

The `moveGroup` method does a bunch of cache management including invalidation of the new group and its parent.  This solved my problem; I now see all of my groups in the admin console (following a page reload) after they are created via my provider.  The groups are also available via API calls to get the list of groups for the realm.